# Dynamically removing and adding JavaSript file

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dynamic

I am trying to add and remove js file dynamically by using the technique of add and remove html elements :

```
  function start(){
      var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');
          scriptElement.src = 'js/game_page.js'; 
          scriptElement.id = "game1";
          document.body.appendChild(scriptElement);
      }
       start();
       function stop(){
        var a = document.getElementById("game1");
        a.parentNode.removeChild(a);
       }
        stop();
```

In this case,the js file which is appended in DOM is still working even after calling `stop()`
Also share if any other way so that I could do the following thing,

Expectation:

Algorithm :

```
 add work1.js
onclick of  button{
  if(condition1)
  {
     remove work1.js //may contain same declarations,so removing is also important
     add work2.js
  }
  else
  {
     if(work2.js present)
     {
       remove work2.js
       add work1.js
     } 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript is loaded with the page, individual script files cannot be loaded/unloaded after the page has loaded.

If you are trying to make certain code run only when a button is pressed, perhaps you can contain it in a function, or the method of an object and run it from there:

```
let lastRun = null;
onclick of  button{
  if(condition1)
  {
     removeWork1(); // Function that undoes whatever work1 creates.
     work2();
     lastRun = "work2";
  }
  else
  {
     if(lastRun === "work2")
     {
       lastRun = "work1";
       work1();     } 
  }
}
```

It would be a lot easier to help you with your situation if you update your question to include what code would be running from these scripts. Are you trying to modify the dom, change the page?

Comment: In this context, removing work1() and adding work2() looked complicated so I found solution like I duplicated same html file with work2.js  linked and make first.html to navigate to second.html